# How to create a rectangle with a circular shape and grey border color in CSS?

Tags: css, svg

Can anybody tell me is it possible to make a shape only using CSS.
The below image show what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

SVG

```html
<svg width="310" height="99" viewBox="0 0 310 99" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<mask id="path-1-inside-1_32_991" fill="white">
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M93.0225 16.459H301.683C305.931 16.459 309.375 19.9029 309.375 24.1513V81.7227C309.375 85.971 305.931 89.415 301.683 89.415H85.4445C77.2444 95.4405 67.1196 99 56.1635 99C45.2074 99 35.0826 95.4405 26.8826 89.415H7.69232C3.44398 89.415 0 85.971 0 81.7227V24.1513C0 19.9029 3.44396 16.459 7.69231 16.459H19.3045C28.3671 6.35593 41.5231 0 56.1635 0C70.804 0 83.9599 6.35593 93.0225 16.459Z"/>
</mask>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M93.0225 16.459H301.683C305.931 16.459 309.375 19.9029 309.375 24.1513V81.7227C309.375 85.971 305.931 89.415 301.683 89.415H85.4445C77.2444 95.4405 67.1196 99 56.1635 99C45.2074 99 35.0826 95.4405 26.8826 89.415H7.69232C3.44398 89.415 0 85.971 0 81.7227V24.1513C0 19.9029 3.44396 16.459 7.69231 16.459H19.3045C28.3671 6.35593 41.5231 0 56.1635 0C70.804 0 83.9599 6.35593 93.0225 16.459Z" fill="white"/>
<path d="M93.0225 16.459L92.2781 17.1267L92.5762 17.459H93.0225V16.459ZM85.4445 89.415V88.415H85.1166L84.8523 88.6091L85.4445 89.415ZM26.8826 89.415L27.4747 88.6091L27.2105 88.415H26.8826V89.415ZM19.3045 16.459V17.459H19.7509L20.0489 17.1267L19.3045 16.459ZM93.0225 17.459H301.683V15.459H93.0225V17.459ZM301.683 17.459C305.379 17.459 308.375 20.4552 308.375 24.1513H310.375C310.375 19.3507 306.483 15.459 301.683 15.459V17.459ZM308.375 24.1513V81.7227H310.375V24.1513H308.375ZM308.375 81.7227C308.375 85.4187 305.379 88.415 301.683 88.415V90.415C306.483 90.415 310.375 86.5233 310.375 81.7227H308.375ZM301.683 88.415H85.4445V90.415H301.683V88.415ZM84.8523 88.6091C76.8181 94.5128 66.8995 98 56.1635 98V100C67.3398 100 77.6707 96.3682 86.0366 90.2208L84.8523 88.6091ZM56.1635 98C45.4275 98 35.5089 94.5128 27.4747 88.6091L26.2904 90.2208C34.6564 96.3682 44.9873 100 56.1635 100V98ZM26.8826 88.415H7.69232V90.415H26.8826V88.415ZM7.69232 88.415C3.99626 88.415 1 85.4187 1 81.7227H-1C-1 86.5233 2.8917 90.415 7.69232 90.415V88.415ZM1 81.7227V24.1513H-1V81.7227H1ZM1 24.1513C1 20.4552 3.99625 17.459 7.69231 17.459V15.459C2.89168 15.459 -1 19.3507 -1 24.1513H1ZM7.69231 17.459H19.3045V15.459H7.69231V17.459ZM20.0489 17.1267C28.9299 7.22618 41.8189 1 56.1635 1V-1C41.2272 -1 27.8044 5.48568 18.5601 15.7912L20.0489 17.1267ZM56.1635 1C70.5081 1 83.3972 7.22618 92.2781 17.1267L93.7669 15.7912C84.5226 5.48568 71.0998 -1 56.1635 -1V1Z" fill="#D0D1D2" mask="url(#path-1-inside-1_32_991)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Entirely depends on your HTML.

Comment: using just one <div> element.. <div class="container"></div>

Comment: Your .container may have a :before shaped like a circle and a filter:drop-shadow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like below:

```css
.box {
  --c: #f2f2f2; /* the background color */

  height: 250px; 
  border: 30px solid #0000;
  border-radius: 40px; /* a litte bigger than the border to have a visual radius (10px in this case) */
  background: /* adjust the 200px to control the offset of the circle */
   radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 200px 50%,var(--c) 98%,#0000) border-box,
   linear-gradient(var(--c) 0 0) padding-box;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px #000); /* the shadow part */ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```